# How to get Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS play h265 videos?

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04, repository, codecs

I am trying to play h265 videos in Ubuntu. I tried adding the `strukturag/libde265` PPA, but I get the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:strukturag/libde265
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Obviously, the PPA does not support my Ubuntu version.

So how do I play h265 videos o Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: the PPA you are trying to use does not support Focal.  that PPA will not work.

Answer (score 1):

You will need the codecs, but whether you can smoothly play h265 will depend on the CPU.

First, remove the outdated with PPA `sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:strukturag/libde265`

Then, install all the necessary codecs with `sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Comment: Is that the only command I need?  'cause my VLC still isn't playing h265...

Comment: Firstly, use the APT vlc instead of the snap one. `sudo snap remove VLC && sudo apt install vlc`. If the issue persists, can you run `vlc /path/to/video/file` and post the output?

Comment: Here's the output: vlc /home/aj/Videos/1_01_R_20231208162407.h265
VLC media player 3.0.9.2 Vetinari (revision 3.0.9.2-0-gd4c1aefe4d)
[0000557a2390a5b0] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.